# What Intent Filter can I use to capture intent calls to the permissions screen on the Android Market?

Tags: android, google-play, intentfilter

I am creating an app that warns users about strange permission requests before they download an app from the *Android Market* (such as a wallpaper app that requests to read a user's contact information). Is there a way to capture the intent called when a user presses the **install** button and is shown the list of **uses-permissions**?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way of doing this that I know of. You can show the user your dialog right after the user installs the app instead (in most cases, before they run it):

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED"/>
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Receiver.java

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          try {
              PackageManager manager = this.getPackageManager();
              PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo(
                  intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart(), 0);
              Toast.makeText(context, "Look at these suspicious permissions:"+
                  info.permissions, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say *in most cases, before they run it*, do you mean to say that there are cases between when an app installs and it is run? For example, could a service launch immediately?

Comment: Just put that code I gave you in your project, try to install apps from Market and try to open them as soon they are installed. In most cases, you lose the competition and the receiver gets called before you even clicked the Open button, and even if you click it before the broadcast is fired, your code still gets executed.

Comment: Well, this isn't quite the answer I wanted, but without doing some major hacking, this is my best bet (I tried working on a *c2dm hijack*, but the Android Market uses signature verification, and without knowing how to access the packets themselves, this will have to do).