# Send an sms during apk instalation or when finish it

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I wrote an application and I need to send sms. I think that it is a good idea to do it during the application installation or when installation is finished.

It is correct? If it is correct, how can I do it?

Comment: BTW, you should validate an answer or nobody will answer you anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you cannot get control during application installation.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040597/what-intent-filter-can-i-use-to-capture-intent-calls-to-the-permissions-screen-o/8041778#8041778) question asked how to intercept an intent during a download. I personally tried by getting the Android Market source code and working on a c2dm hijack, however because it verifies its c2dm transmission with the app signature, it is about impossible (and very much frowned upon) to spoof, and without rooting the phone, you cannot listen to packets coming in on the network interface. Your best bet is to send the text **after** your application has installed (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040597/what-intent-filter-can-i-use-to-capture-intent-calls-to-the-permissions-screen-o/8041778#8041778)).